# asyncio delayed StreamReader.read

Tags: pygame, python-asyncio, python-3.5

I'm kinda new to asyncio and async def/await syntax, so I wanted to ask how exactly should I do something like this:

```
import asyncio
import pygame
import logging
from pygame import *
log = logging.getLogger('')


class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.create_client())

    async def create_client(self):
        self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.host, 
                                                                 self.port, 
                                                                 loop=self.loop)
        asyncio.ensure_future(self._handle_packets(), loop=self.loop)

    async def _handle_packets(self):
        while True:
            data = await self.reader.read(4096)
            if not data:
                continue
            message = data.decode()
            log.debug("(NET) Received "+message)

    def send(self, data):
        self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.ensure_future(self._send(data),
                                                           loop=self.loop))

    async def _send(self, data):
        self.writer.write(data)
        await self.writer.drain()
        print("_send done")

    def disconnect(self):
        print("DC")
        self.loop.close()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Pyond client")
    bg = Surface((640, 480))
    bg.fill(Color("#004400"))
    client = Client('127.0.0.1', 2508)
    while True:
        pygame.event.pump()
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                raise SystemExit
            elif e.type == KEYUP:
                if e.key == K_UP:
                    client.send(b"{'Hello':'World'}")
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
    client.disconnect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code creates 640x480 window with pygame, then reads for incoming K_UP (up arrow) key. Upon pressing, sends json-like string to the server. `_handle_packets` was supposed to read any incoming data from server and just print it.
I was testing this code and sending works okay, but receiving is quite delayed. I'm sure I need to put handler somewhere else, so where exactly?
And btw, send works only once. Need help on this one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems here.

The first one is pretty **fundamental**. The `asycnio` event loop stops running after `create_client()` finishes, and only runs again **while** you `send()` data. So, the only time it is able to run `_handle_packets` is when you are `send()`ing. Ideally, you should start the event loop once in a higher scope and close it once you are done with everything.

The second problem is that whenever you `client.send(b"{'Hello':'World'}")`, you will block the outer `pygame` `while True` loop, preventing any other events to be processed until the previous one is sent. You should make use of a `asyncio.Queue` to queue the events & send them from the `Client` class.

Here are some changes I would make (sorry, untested; I don't have `pygame` installed ATM):

```
# vim: tabstop=4 expandtab

import asyncio
import pygame
import logging
from pygame import *
log = logging.getLogger('')


class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, port, loop):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.loop = loop
        self.send_q = asyncio.Queue()

    async def connect(self):
        self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.host, 
                                                                 self.port, 
                                                                 loop=self.loop)
        self.loop.create_task(self._handle_packets())
        self.loop.create_task(self._send())

    async def _handle_packets(self):
        while True:
            data = await self.reader.read(4096)
            if not data:
                continue
            message = data.decode()
            log.debug("(NET) Received "+message)

    def send(self, data):
        self.send_q.put_nowait(data)

    async def _send(self):
        while True:
            data = await self.send_q.get()
            self.writer.write(data)
            await self.writer.drain()

    def disconnect(self):
        print("DC")
        self.writer.close()


async def main(loop):
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Pyond client")
    bg = Surface((640, 480))
    bg.fill(Color("#004400"))
    client = Client('127.0.0.1', 2508, loop)
    await client.connect()
    while True:
        pygame.event.pump()
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                raise SystemExit
            elif e.type == KEYUP:
                if e.key == K_UP:
                    client.send(b"{'Hello':'World'}")
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
    client.disconnect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
    loop.close()
```

Another **important** thing to keep in mind is that you should never block the `asyncio` event loop with `pygame`, otherwise the `Client` network processing in the background will stall. I've never used `pygame`, so I'm not familiar with which `pygame` function might be "blocking", but they should be called using `result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_func, *func_args)`. This will call blocking functions in another thread.